# spring injection without constructor and setter

Tags: java, spring

I have the question. If my class has dependency like:

```
public class Test {
   public Depend depend;

   //Here methods
}
```

And it **does not** have setter for *Depend* property or constructor with *Depend* as argument, and it has no annotation for Spring but has **xml** config like:

```
<bean id="depend" class="xxx.Depend"></bean>

<bean id="test" class="xxx.Test">
   <property name="depend" ref="depend" />
</bean>
```

Is it possible to inject *Depend* into *Test* using such config (actually his config does not work. I just wonder - can I change smth to make it work not using annotations or setter/constructor)?

Comment: What will happen if you test it before posting it as a question?

Comment: I wrote - "this config does not work"!!! My question is in class "wondering". I wonder: is it possible to make it work without setter/constructor or annotation. In python you can overwrite property directly.

Comment: The "actually (t)his config does not work" sounds like "I tested it" to me...

Comment: The wrong results are the answer.

Comment: @GoodBadandUgly you said "it *is* possible". Really? Can you post an example?

Comment: @ Keith The answer is **NO**. It is **not** possible.Missed not somehow. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible without annotations, but you would need to create a TestBeanFactory and then create an object of Test and set Depend yourself before returning it.

```
<bean id="depend" class="xxx.Depend"></bean>
<bean id="testFactory" class="xxx.TestFactory">
    <property name="depend" ref="depend" />
</bean>

<bean id="test" factory-bean="testFactory" factory-method="createTest">
</bean>
```

Then your test factory would look something like this.

```
public class TestFactory {
    private Depend depend;
    
    public setDepend(Depend depend) {
        this.depend = depend
    }

    public Test createTest() {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.depend = this.depend;
        return test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without using annotations.

Your current configuration needs some simple changes to make this work. Annotate the `depend` field with `@Autowired` and enable component scanning.

Here's a detailed explanation: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/

Comment: OP's question is not about adding an annotation for this case.

Comment: That's true -- I guess I should have been explicit and said "no, not possible, but you can do this..."

Comment: Please edit your post and add that part in order to convert it into a valid answer :)

Comment: Yes)  I know about annotations)